# How to test if the case classes I have created for the parser are correct using json4s libraries in scala?

Tags: json, scala, parsing, testing, json4s

I have a huge json object and I need to parse it and then write some tests to see if everything goes as expected.

```
case class User(id: Identification, age:Int, name: String ...)
case class Identification(id: Int, hash: String ....)
... a lot more classes
```

Now I'm trying to write the tests

```
val json = parse(Source.fromFile(/path).getLines.mkString("\n"))
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
```

So my question is how can i test if the case classes are ok?
I thought maybe I should try to extract for ex. the users and then to check parameter by parameter if they are correct, but I don't thing that is a good way because it is not me who created the json so I'm not interested about the content.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found working with JSON and case classes overt the years the minimum to test.

This three things should be tested always

## Serialization with deserialiaztion combined

```
val example = MyCaseClass()
read[MyCaseClass](write(example)) should Equal example
```

Checks if a class can be transformed to JSON, read back and still has the same values. This one breaks more often than one would think.

## Deserialization: `JSON String` -> `CaseClasses`

```
val exampleAsJSON : String
val exampleAsCaseClass : MyCaseClass

read(exampleAsJSON) shouldEqual exampleAsCaseClass
```

Checks if JSON still can be deserialized.

## Serialization: `CaseClasses` -> `JSON String`

```
 val exampleAsJSON : String
 val exampleAsCaseClass : MyCaseClass

 write(exampleAsCaseClass) shouldEqual exampleAsJSON
```

Checks if String/ JSON Representation stays stable. Here it is hard to keep the data up to date and often some not nice whitespace changes lead to false alarms.

## Additional things to test

Are there `optional` parameters present? If yes all tests should be done with and without the optional parameters.

Comment: Normaly: If the object can be serialized it can be also use when it is contained within another object. So you only need a custom serializer for the special cases.